# Getopts: how to print uninitialized stick?

Tags: bash, getopt, getopts

How to print uninitialized stick?

```
while getopts ":n" opt; do
    case $opt in
        n)
            blablabla ;;
        ?)
            echo "Unknown stick: $opt" ;;
    esac
done
```

In that case, it always print `Unknown stick: ?`. But in case `-a` stick, I want to print `Unknown stick: -a`

Comment: By "*stick*" you mean a short option or a *flag*? i.e. a alphanumeric character prefixed with a `-`?

Comment: by stick I mean "-a"

Comment: You want `$opt` to be empty if `-a` or some other value is used?

Comment: if I put command: myScript.sh -a
I want to print: Unknown stick: -a

Answer (score 0):

use this script:

```
option=$1
while getopts ":n" opt; do
    case $opt in
        n)
            blablabla ;;
        ?)
            echo "Unknown stick: $option" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: What happens when `n` has a value?

Comment: What happens in the case of `-n value`? The op intends to have a value for n if I understand correctly

Comment: If the chosen option has listed in `case list` then opt will have the option we have chosen; not value. if the option not listed in `case list` it will return `?`

Comment: I have totally changed my answer. can you try this?

Comment: Do you have any option with value?

Comment: The normal behavior of getopts is, if the chosen option has listed along with getopts, then only opt variable get that value. If still you need to get your output, then you need to implement in our on logic without using getopts. Normally people do the default case to show the syntax of usage rather than you requirement. Feel free to ask if any clarification is needed in my comments.